# Phantomjs: Function sending a keypress event doesn't work with enter

Tags: javascript, node.js, phantomjs, dom-events, keycode

I am trying to automate some things only with phantomjs. Doing the same work with casperjs works but the challenge is to get it working only with phantomjs.
I want to press enter in a normal textfield which I have focused on.

```
page.sendEvent('keypress', page.event.key.A); //this works
page.sendEvent('keypress', page.event.key.Enter); //this doesn't work
```

The script runs without any errors but in the output I can see that the enter event did not work.

I tested another function which worked:

```
page.sendEvent('keypress', page.event.key.A); //this works
page.sendEvent('keypress', page.event.key.Backspace); //this works
```

Why is only the enter event not working? Every other key works. Is there a way to do it with keycodes?

Comment: This may have something to do with the page you're automating/testing. I tried on SO and it is the other way around: https://gist.github.com/artjomb/87ec080f37b609fee288

Comment: have you tried page.event.key.Return?